# Who operates WeExchange, the first Ripple Gateway?

Tags: ripple

Is it operated by OpenCoin, the company behind Ripple?

https://weexchange.co/

https://ripple.com/wiki/Gateway_List

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.

The [contact](https://weexchange.co/?page=helpcontact) page lists

1. WeExchange Australia, Pty. Ltd.
2. WeExchange, Inc

Of course, I don't know that for a fact. The whois is registered to a privacy protection company, which doesn't really fill me with confidence.

Comment: +1 rule #1: never give your money to someone who doesn't even tell you his name...